# Количество записей в базе без NULL laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

```
DB::table('user_items')
        ->groupBy('rating')
        ->count();
```

На выходе получается :2

[image: База данных]

Как сделать в точности на оборот? Чтоб считало количество записей в колонке не учитывая NULL;
Laravel V8

Comment: А если так:
DB::table('user_items')
        ->groupBy('rating')
        ->count('rating');
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вначале следуют отфильтровать поля, в которых рейтинг не указан, а уже после этого группировать:

```
DB::table('user_items')
        ->where('rating' '!=' null)
        ->groupBy('rating')
        ->count();
```

Желательно, чтобы вы уточнили изначальную задачу, которую пытаетесь выполнить данным кодом

Если вам нажно количество записей, которые не ровны `null`, достаточно будет сделать:

```
DB::table('user_items')
        ->where('rating' '!=' null)
        ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('user_items')
  ->whereNotNull('rating')
  ->count();
```

Comment: Почему вы не читаете вопрос, прежде чем ответить?

Comment: Почему же не читаю?

Comment: Что, по вашему автор хотел узнать? количество записей с рейтингом не null?

Comment: Именно это же  "Чтоб считало количество записей в колонке не учитывая NULL"

Answer (score 0):

```php
DB::table('user_items')
  ->whereNotNull('rating')
  ->groupBy('rating')
  ->count();
```